# How to get all guilds where a member is in?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I know how to get all members from a guild but I need to do the opposite operation : Getting all the guilds (IDs) where a specified member is registered in.

When fetching user like this `client.users.cache.get(memberID);` I don't see anything in the result that can allow me to see all the member's guilds :

```
User {
  id: '706498754712807398',
   system: null,
   locale: null,
 flags: UserFlags { bitfield: 0 },
   username: 'johndoe',
   bot: false,
  discriminator: '1023',
   avatar: null,
   lastMessageID: null,
   lastMessageChannelID: null
 }
```

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using the following code:

```js
const userID = '3383083830389'; // the ID of the user
const guilds = client.guilds.cache.filter((guild) => guild.members.cache.has(userID));
```

and `guilds` is a `Collection` of guilds where the user is in. This has two limitations :

- you can only get the guilds where the bot is in too
- this won't work if the member is not cached (this can be resolved by trying to fetch the member in each guild)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot view servers that a user is in that you do not have access to the account. This is a Discord limitation and falls under the privacy category, you don't want to do this anyways as it can be used maliciously.

The only way you can access the guilds a user is in if you are logged in as that account, otherwise without logging into that account, you cannot see what kind of servers they are in.

But if you want to check what kind of servers your bot is in, the code is quiet simple.

```
const allGuilds = (client.guilds.cache)
console.log(allGuilds)
```

I have not tested this myself, but it should point you in the right direction.